# simulate an adaptive inderse dynamic tracking control algorithm and the adaptive Lyapunov based tracking control algorithm for the 3-DOF manipulator

Tags: matlab

1. Design the adaptive inverse dynamics tracking control algorithm and the
   adaptive Lyapunov based tracking control algorithm for the 3-DOF manipulator.
   Simulate the motion of the robot controlled by these algorithms
   for different trajectories and various values of gains (such as Kp, Kd, Λ,
   Γ, etc.) Compare the performance of these algorithms and make conclusions/
   recommendations.
2. Design the parallel control algorithm for the 3-DOF manipulator. Simulate
   the process of interaction between the 3-DOF robot controlled by the
   parallel control algorithm and an environment, for various values of gains
   and parameters of the environment. Make conclusions/recommendations.

simulink Matlab code

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)